# Questions with new activity banner is repeated rather than updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

When I have visiting the site today I noticed that [the banner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125677/163868) that says

> *x* questions with new activity

is repeated over the last such banner rather than updated as *x* is increased. Is this a bug?

For an example see the following:

[image: Example of how the questions with new activity banner is repeated five times rather than replaced]

I was able [to reproduce the problem later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZojwW.png). I was also able to reproduce it on [Ask Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0roPv.png) and [Super User](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9Hih.png). I was not not able to reproduce it on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Programmers or English Language and Usage.

I am running Firefox 12.0 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I think this "n questions with new activity" should vanish altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are still having issues on a site please force refresh your browser.